# Burninate [numbers]

Tags: discussion, burninate-request

[numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numbers) doesn't convey any useful information about the question.

- For complex numbers, we have [complex-numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/complex-numbers).
- For floating point numbers, we have [floating-point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floating-point) and [double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/double) (the later may need some clean up, but not relevant in this request), among other related concepts
- For integer, we have [integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/integer), [long-integer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/long-integer) and other related concepts (they may need some clean up also, but also not relevant here).

Should we burninate [numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/numbers) and retag the questions with something else more meaningful?

Comment: I agree, I personally think that if you cannot be an 'expert' in a tag, it shouldn't exist. It's not possible to be an expert of [tag:numbers] and for that reason it should be nuked.

Comment: @cybermonkey By that logic, all the other types of number tags (from the post) should be also burninated, because it is equally hard to be an "expert" in those. Maybe a case can be made that all the types of number that programmers can think of are already present as tags and the [numbers] tag is too unspecific.

Comment: @ArtjomB, actually, people can be and are experts at floating point, fixed-width integer, and various other sorts of numerical representations. Floating point is really tricky to use properly, and there are loads of "bit hacks" to calculate integer stuff quickly, and designing arbitrary-precision representations is an art of its own.

Comment: I understand that there might be things you want to discuss about the other tags, but please keep the discussion to [tag:numbers] tag, and make a new burninate request if you think any of the other tags should be burned. Thanks.

Comment: What if the issue is that the OP misused a type, for instance the age old "using a double to represent money".

Comment: @Aron: The goal is to remove the tag. Ideally, everyone would edit each question manually and fix up the problems along the way, but in case there are too many, a mod may use their tool to nuke the tag directly without other edits to the question. (This is how tag burninate works around here, I suppose).

Comment: @nhahtdh, actually, it's all done manually.

Comment: @dfeuer: There have been cases in the past where mods did the retagging en masse in the past (for thousands of posts), so I think the feature is there, but it is rarely used and the tagging is done manually, since we also want to clean up bad questions.

Comment: 8400 questions!!!!, the amount of work would be huge, the benefit probably very small, it does not seem like a tag that generates off-topic questions or introduce confusion, the tag is mostly useless, but don't do any real damage.

Answer (score -5):

I wouldn't remove that tag, but I may agree that probably it could use some cleaning up or rephrasing the tag's description to indicate that it is a general topic.

Why not remove?

[First example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901102/how-to-print-a-number-with-commas-as-thousands-separators-in-javascript)
[Second example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18082/validate-decimal-numbers-in-javascript-isnumeric)

What could be proposed as a replacement for the "numbers" tag there? I feel that this tag fits at it is.

While the first example is in fact arguable, as "dot" is present only with floats/doubles (let's ignore potential fixed-point numbers, whether they exist in that language/platform at all or not), the question is focused on formatting numbers first, so I'd leave that. I'd change it to "double" if someone asked about precisely that datatype, or the IEEE specs, etc.

The second example is more evident: validation of precisely numbers. Not just any validation. Not just integers or doubles. For me, removing the 'numbers' tag from it as wrong as removing 'validation' tag.

Those two examples actually could use some 'number-formatting' or 'number-parsing' tags. But "numbers" feel more natural and brief to summarize the topic. Just like "loops" or "conventions" tags.

Comment: "What could be proposed as a replacement for the "numbers" tag there?" - Not using a tag at all. "Formatting" and "Validation" are completely sufficient. We don't care if OP formats or validates numbers, strings, objects, animals, whatever. Why do you feel that those tags need to have more context? Furthermore, what use is the tag on its own?

Comment: My opinion is that they don't need [tag:numbers] tags. They are not any more easily accessible via tag, than searching for keyword.